# I have a few questions about the code TWIG?

Tags: twig

I have a code TWIG :

```
{% set foo = 1 %}

{% set items = [foo] %}
```

let me ask why :

```
{% set items = [foo] %}
```

does not work?

Please let me know the reason and how to solve it.
I want it to work in `[]` .
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works with the most recent version of twig:

```
{% set a = 30 %}
{% set b = 60 %}
{% set c = a + b %}

{% set d = [a,2,3,b,c] %}

a: {{a}} {# echos 30 #}
b: {{b}} {# echos 60 #}
c: {{c}} {# echos 90 (a+b) #}
d[0]: {{d[0]}} {# echos 30 (a) #}
d[1]: {{d[1]}} {# echos 2 #}
d[2]: {{d[2]}} {# echos 3 #}
d[3]: {{d[3]}} {# echos 60 (b) #}
d[4]: {{d[4]}} {# echos 90 (c) #}

{% set e = {a: 15} %}

e.a: {{e.a}} {# echos 15 #}
```

I guess your problem is about how to access the values, so I included some of the accessing methods of twig.

I hope this solves your problem.